# Azure App Gateway gives Error 404 but backend probe is healthy

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have setup my Application Gateway and added a CNMAME in my domain to point to the DNS Name of the application gateway. The application gateway will point to 3 sites eventually . I created 3 web apps and have added each to the backend pool . I initially used the default HTTP Settings (appGatewayBackendHttpSettings
) but realised I needed to point to 3 health probes so I duplicated this HTTP Setting and allocated it to one of the listerners and pointed this to a health probe for one of the site.

I then configured my applicationgateway as below but get a 404 error when navigating to the site even though the probe shows its healthy.

```
mydomainListener
Frontend IP Configuration : appGatewayFrontendIP 
FrontendPort : appGatewayFrontendPort (443)
hostname : test.mydomain.com
Protocol : HTTPS
Certificate : test-cert
Associated Rule : testRule

TestRule
Type: Basic
Backendpool:testBackendPool
HTTP setting : testHTTPSetting

testHTTPSetting
Cookie based affinity : Disabled
Connection draining : Disabled
Protocol : HTTPS
Port : 443
Backend authentication certificates :mycert
Use a Custom Prove : testHTTPSProbe
Request Timeout : 30

testHTTPSProbe: 
Host : test-azurewebsites.net
Protcol  : HTTPS
Path : /
Interval : 30 
Timeout 30
Unhealthy Threshold : 3
Minimum healthy servers :0
```

Comment: what does the backend health report? does it report healthy?

Comment: when i click on Backend health it shows probe as healthy and Success which is why I dont know why Im getting error 404

Answer (score 6):

Ok, i suspect this is due to the fact that you need to configure your webapps to use custom domain names. When request comes to them the request is looking for mydomain.com, but your websites only listen on test.azurewebsites.net.

Navigate to webapp > custom domain > plus icon > validate > add. You can read linked article for more details and also follow on screen prompts

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain

ps. alternatively you can use backend `hostname` property to send hostname to backend servers

reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/application-gateway/http-settings?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-application-gateway-http-settings-create
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-gateway/applicationgateways/createorupdate#applicationgatewaybackendhttpsettings

Comment: the 3 websites which will be part of this app gateway will be test.mydomain.com, preprod.mydomain.com and prod.mydomain.com. In my DNS all these have cnames poiting to the application gateway. If I add the custom domains to dns what aboutn the cnames for these websites whicj already point to the application gateway. Do i need to keep these ?

Comment: also what is backend hostname property? can you advise

Comment: you can keep these, but you need to add each custom dns name to appropriate webapp so it will listen on that dns name

Comment: ill try that, also what is the backendhostname property option?

Comment: ok ive asked the client to add a cname to the webapp which already points the the application gateway and they are saying they cant add an additional cname?? If the DNS of test.mydomain.com points to the app gateway they are saying they cannot add another cname in their DNS pointing to the web app as well. This is very confusing and badly documented.. Help much appreciated

Comment: i think you can use txt dns name to verify it, check the first link I've sent it. this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-web-sites-custom-domain#create-an-a-record-and-txt-record. also this - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/07538e12-d0ae-4435-b914-3ad8523488d9/cant-use-a-custom-domain-in-app-service?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Comment: yes but can yo have the same  cname pointing to app gateway and web app ? where is this in the docs? I cant see it

Comment: you dont need that, you only need to verify and add that custom dns name, after that you can repoint the dns back to app gateway, if txt\a records do not work for you

Comment: i did that now i get error 403 web app is stopped hen your connection is not private

Comment: that means you didnt add a certificate to the webapp, you need to use hostname to access the webapp on its internal azure name

Comment: i added ssl cert and bound it, it still says error 403 web app not started yet the backend health shows ok as do the azure diagnostics however when i navigate to the website using https://test.mydoman.com says web app not started error 403???

Comment: use hosts file and point test.mydomain.com to the webapp and see what error you get