# Azure App Gateway Back-End Health State Flipping

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

I have an Azure App Gateway connected to 3 different App Service apps all running as part of the same App Service Plan (3 different back-end pools). In the **Backend Health** section of the AG, one of the app/pool is constantly flipping between **Healthy** and **Unknown** states. I have checked the entire network configuration according to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-backend-health-troubleshooting#backend-health-status-unknown) and everything seems to be configured properly.

I have configured ip restrictions on the app services according to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions) specifying the subnet the AG resides in as allowed. I have also temporarily allowed my ip address and every time the health for the 1 app goes to "unknown", I am still able to access the app service using its native .azurewebsites.net url locally on my machine.

Any ideas how I can troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below points help to work around the issue.

As a workaround initially,try to restart the application gateway after the backend is deployed .
Also check this discussion on [github issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/48261#issuecomment-1072973821)

> Sometimes Appgateway will cache the response indefinitely and the fix
> maybe "Dynamic DNS" which ensures that the "no existing domain" is not
> cached on the Appgw.Also check for the fix using v16.

Also  check this > [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51703441/azure-app-gateway-gives-error-404-but-backend-probe-is-healthy?rq=1) which says to use custom domain names as the request looks for some domain.